# How to find text on HTML page loaded on c# webview, highlight text and scroll webview to text position?

Tags: c#, webview, scroll, highlight

How to find text on HTML page loaded on c# webview, highlight text and scroll webview to text position ?

I have tried this code but returns "System.Exception: 'Exceção de HRESULT: 0x80020101'"

```
private async void WebView1_NavigationCompleted(object sender, 
WebViewControlNavigationCompletedEventArgs e)

{
        string searchFunc;
        searchFunc = @"function search(text) {
                       var element = $(""*:            contains(text):first"");
                       window.scrollTop(element.offset().top);
                    }";
         await webView1.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { searchFunc + " search('RELACIONAMENTO');" });
     }
```