# Edit->Find for WebView2 UI Component (WPF/C#/javascript)

Tags: javascript, c#, wpf

I need to implement "Edit->Find" function for a WebView2 UI Component using WPF/C#/javascript... Below you will find two examples:  One that is made for a TextBox UI Control called MainWindow1, and the other that is implemented for a WebView2 UI Control that is called MainWindows2.  I'm giving both examples because I need to work the same way for each one. The TextBox example is working, but the WebView2 example is missing some javascript code to finish it and maybe requires some tweeting of the C# calls to WebView2.

First, I implemented a "Find Forward" button for a TextBox that I can click multiple times to find the next string matching the search pattern in the textbox.  And Here's my XML and C# for it:

**MainWindow1 GUI:**

[image: Mainwindow1]

**MainWindow1 XML:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded"
        Title="MainWindow1" Height="450" Width="800">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  
               DockPanel.Dock="Top" Background="Aqua">
            <TextBox Name="TboxFind" Width="80" Text="id"/>
            <Button Name="FindForward" Content="FindForward"
                    Click="FindForward_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <TextBox Name="textbox1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>

    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow1 C#:**

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows; using System.Windows.Controls;
namespace WpfApp1 {
  public partial class MainWindow1 : Window {
    public MainWindow1() {InitializeComponent();}
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
      string text1 = "";
      for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        text1 = text1 + "id" + i.ToString() + "\n";}
      textbox1.Text = text1;textbox1.Focus();textbox1.CaretIndex = 0;
    }
    private void TextBoxGotoLine(TextBox textbox1, int linenum) {
      var target_cpos 
         = textbox1.GetCharacterIndexFromLineIndex(linenum);
      var target_char_rect 
         = textbox1.GetRectFromCharacterIndex(target_cpos);
      var first_char_rect = textbox1.GetRectFromCharacterIndex(0);
            textbox1.ScrollToVerticalOffset(target_char_rect.Top 
                  - first_char_rect.Top);
    }
    private void FindForward_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
      string pattern = @"(?i)(" + Regex.Escape(TboxFind.Text) + @")";
      string text1 = textbox1.Text.Substring(
          textbox1.CaretIndex + textbox1.SelectionLength);
      var match1 = Regex.Match(text1, pattern);
      if (match1.Success) {
        textbox1.Focus();
        textbox1.Select(textbox1.CaretIndex 
         + textbox1.SelectionLength 
         + match1.Index, match1.Groups[0].Length);
      } //if
    } //function
}/*class*/  }/*namespace*/
```

The problem I'm having is that I also need this same feature for a WebView2 UI Control.

So I install the WebView2 UI Control:

**WebView2 Install:**

- PM > Install-Package Microsoft.Web.WebView2
- Add to XML: xmlns:wv2="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf;assembly=Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf"
- using Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core;

And here's my corresponding XML and C# demo code that should work the same as the first example I have given:

**MainWindow2 GUI:**

[image: Mainwindow2]

**MainWindows2 XML:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow2"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:wv2
="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf;assembly=Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf"        
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Loaded="Window_Loaded"
Title="MainWindow2" Height="450" Width="800" >
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  
                 DockPanel.Dock="Top" Background="Aqua">
            <TextBox Name="SearchStr" Width="80" Text="id"/>
            <Button Name="FindForward" 
                 Content="FindForward" Click="FindForward_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <wv2:WebView2 Name="webview2" CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted
          ="webview2_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted" />

    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow2 C#:**

```
using System.Windows;  using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core;
namespace WpfApp1 {
  public partial class MainWindow2 : Window {
  public MainWindow2() {InitializeComponent(); SearchStr.Focus(); }
  private async void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    await webview2.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();   
  }
        
  private void webview2_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(
    object sender, CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs e)
  {
    string html = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      string id = "id" + i.ToString();
      html = html + "<b>" + id + "</b><br/>";
    }
    webview2.CoreWebView2.NavigateToString(html);
  }
  private async Tasks.Task<string> Find(string pattern) {
    string js = "";
    js = js + "var m1 = document.getElementById(""body"")";
    js = js + "/*... ??? what goes here ??? */";
    // Find and highlight one at a time, and scroll into view ...
    // repeat find from beginning of html body when done ...
    // See MainWindow1 example with TextBox for desired behavior here.
    return await webview2.ExecuteScriptAsync(js);
  }
  private void async FindForward_Click(object s, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    await Find(SearchStr.Text);
  }
}/*class*/  }/*namespace*/
```

How to use WebBrowser UI Control to do a:

```
 Menu->Edit->Find "SearchStr1"
```

When I click FindForward Button? I'm thinking it has something to do with  executing Javascript on the DOM? each time the button is pressed?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73144003/javascript-doc-body-equivalient-of-c-wpf-caretindex-selectionlength-and-selec

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55880562/how-to-find-text-on-html-page-loaded-on-c-sharp-webview-highlight-text-and-scro

Comment: I’m going to propose the idea of extracting the html from the webview in c# then use c# regex.replace to add <mark id=“markid132”> tags around the search … then  use JavaScript to jump sequentially to each markid tag…  sorry JavaScript … too much work for a c# person…